# Kit to read 2D barcode from image for Linux, with PDF417 support

Tags: linux, barcode

I need some simple kit (could be SDK or the best would be simple console app) to read barcode from image file for linux, and mandatory is PDF417 2D code support, any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a commercial SDK to read your PDF417 barcodes on Linux, you may want to consider trying the [LEADTOOLS Barcode SDK for Linux](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/linux). The SDK ships with command line barcode demos in both C and Java which contain the source code that you can reference for how all this is done.

The LEADTOOLS SDK can take in any of the [150+ supported image formats](https://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v19/dh/to/leadtools.topics.leadtools~l.topics.summaryofallsupportedimagefileformats.html) and read the barcodes from them in just a few lines of code. Below is a simple example function in Java of how this would be done:

```
private void readBarcode(DemoData demoData, BarcodeEngine barcodeEngine){
   RasterImage rasterImage = null;
   RasterCodecs rasterCodecs = null;
   try {
      // Create RasterCodecs
      rasterCodecs = new RasterCodecs();
```

// Create a LEAD stream from the input file
     ILeadStream stream = LeadStreamFactory.create(demoData.filePath);

     // Load the raster image
     rasterImage = rasterCodecs.load(stream);

     // Set barcode symbology to PDF417
     BarcodeSymbology[] symbologies = {BarcodeSymbology.PDF417};

     // Read Barcode
     System.out.println("Read Barcode...");
     BarcodeData[] barcodes = barcodeEngine.getReader().readBarcodes(rasterImage, LeadRect.getEmpty(), 0, symbologies);

     // Print out the Barcodes we found
     System.out.println("The image contains " + barcodes.length +" barcodes");
     for(int i = 0; i < barcodes.length; i++) {
        BarcodeData barcode = barcodes[i];
        System.out.println((i + 1) + ". " + barcode.getSymbology() + " --> " + barcode.getValue());
     }
  } catch(Exception exception) {
     System.out.println(exception.getMessage());
  } finally {
     // Dispose the raster codecs
     if (rasterCodecs != null)
        rasterCodecs.dispose();

     // Dispose the raster image
     if (rasterImage != null)
        rasterImage.dispose();
  }
}

Just as a disclaimer. I work for the company that wrote this library.